# PostgreSQL, add prefix to record field in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

the problem is:
is there a query in postgreSQL that will add some prefix to every record specific field? For example let's assume we have table users:

```
**id**    **name**
  1        adam
  2        ewa
```

and i want to get records and add to every id some specific prefix - let's say 'foo_', desirable result:

```
id: 'foo_1', name: adam
id: 'foo_2', name: ewa
```

I know it can be done with Python after retrieving records, but i wonder if possible with query.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efa43/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'foo_'||id::text,
       name
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a concatenation operator  [String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT 'foo_' || id::text FROM table
```